# Defining the heavy-tail index

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

- Consider the following two results, https://arxiv.org/pdf/0907.2261.pdf (Theorem 1.8) and https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.04740.pdf (Theorem 1). In the former a proof of a random vector $\vec{w} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ to be heavy-tailed with index $\alpha$ is obtained by showing that  $\lim_{t\to\infty} t^{\alpha} \Pr(\Vert \vec{w} \Vert  > t) > 0$. In the later it is obtained by showing that $\exists \vec{u} \in S^{n-1}$ and a positive continuous function $f_\alpha$ on $S^{n-1}$ s.t we have $\lim_{t\to\infty} t^{\alpha} \Pr(\langle \vec{u}, \vec{w} \rangle  > t) = f_\alpha (\vec{u})$

  Are these two definitions of the heavy tail index equivalent?
- In works like https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00184-014-0515-7 we see the following definition of ``strictly $\alpha-$stably" distributed random vector $\vec{w}$ i.e for any $m$ independent copies of it say $\vec{w}_1,\ldots,\vec{w}_m$ we must have,
  $$\sum_{i=1}^m \vec{w}_i \overset{\text{in distribution}}{=} m^{\frac {1}{\alpha}} \vec{w}$$

  This a priori looks like another new definition of the heavy tail index $\alpha$.

  Is this equivalent to any of the above 2 definitions and if yes, how?

---

If the ch.f. of $X$ is $\phi_X(t) = \exp(-\sigma^{\alpha}\vert t\vert^{\alpha})$ for some $\sigma >0$ then it is said to be a ``Symmetric $\alpha-$Stable $(\sigma)$". Its a separate question as to how this is a special case of any of the above $3$ definitions - assuming that they are equivalent!

Comment: As for $\alpha$-stability and symmetric alpha stability, there are entirely different and unrelated concepts.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for a unit vector $u$, one has that $\langle u, w \rangle$ is the projection of $w$ in the direction of $u$. Of course this projection is maximized when $u$ is the unit vector in the direction of $w$, in which case $\langle u, w \rangle = |w|$ exactly when $u$ is parallel to $w$. Thus, for any $u$, if one has $\langle u, w \rangle > t$ then
$ t < \langle u, w\rangle \leq \langle w/|w|, w\rangle = |w|$ so $|w| > t$ as well.

Thus $t^\alpha P(\langle u, w\rangle > t) \leq t^\alpha P(|w| > t)$ and taking the liminf we find $0 < f_\alpha(u) \leq \liminf t^\alpha P(|w| > t)$ for all $u$, showing $w$ has a tail at least as heavy as $\alpha$.

On the other hand, if $0 < \lim t^\alpha P(|w| > t)$ this doesn't tell us about the existence of $f_\alpha(u)>0$. Indeed, if $w$ is concentrated on a line, then $P(\langle u, w\rangle > t) = 0$ when $u$ is perpendicular to this line, so the first condition does not imply the second.